# apache pulsar Direct approach with Apache spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-pulsar

There are 2 approaches of integrating apache kafka with apache spark as mentioned [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/streaming-kafka-0-8-integration.html) with pros and cons.

From what i have read there are 2 spark connector for apache pulsar

1. [org.apache.pulsar:pulsar-spark](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/adaptors-spark/)
2. [io.streamnative.connectors:pulsar-spark-connector_2.12](https://github.com/streamnative/pulsar-spark/tree/3.1.1.4)

Can someone please help me understand if

1. they are following receiver based approach or direct approach?
2. What is the core difference between both the connectors?
3. Is there a possibility of data loss if my job fails while it is processing some batch.

Comment: I am also looking answer for this, for me its because pulsar allows schema evolution but using `streamnative` connector spark or not sure what messes up with pulsar schema versioning. schema evolution works with pulsar python client and java client.